# Executing a program as root after startx

Tags: gpio, xorg, sudo

How can I execute a program located in /home/pi/ as root after doing startx?

`touch .xiinitrc` -> `echo "sdltest" > .xiinitrc`

Program starts, of course, with the rights of the user, but it needs to be executed as root. How? Where is the "standard-file" located so that I can add my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via `sudo`.

Open a terminal and type `visudo` and add the following line to the bottom:

```
pi ALL= NOPASSWD: sdltest
```

Now change your command in `.xinitrc` to `sudo sdltest` and the command should run as root without the user having to enter a password.

Comment: No need for `pi ALL= NOPASSWD: sdltest` for me. It broke my sudoers btw but fixed it with `pkexec visudo`. Anyways just doing `sudo ./sdltest` worked for me, thank you! Didn't know it would be that easy...